# Exception in Application start method error in javaFX and eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javafx, jnetpcap

I'm making deteching data communication with javaFX and Jnetpcap. But I have something wrong. First, I didn't have proper JRE Libary. So I fixed. But I had another error. Making JavaFX project, I had error that recent version is not giving some jar files. so I made custom Library and apply. After that, I had so many errors. So I remake projects. And I add "--module-path /"my link" --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml" in "run config-vmarguments".
And I had This error.
Exception in Application start method
"java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException".
What should I do?

(This is every error code)

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1135)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:893)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jnetpcap/Pcap
    at controller.Controller.initialize(Controller.java:37)
    at javafx.fxml@21/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2670)
    at javafx.fxml@21/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2563)
    at javafx.fxml@21/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2531)
    at controller.Main.setLayout(Main.java:31)
    at controller.Main.start(Main.java:24)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:839)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jnetpcap.Pcap
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    ... 15 more
Exception running application controller.Main
```

In up contents, I explained evet attemp.

Comment: You need to add either the `org.jnetpcap` module or the `com.slytechs.jnetpcap.pro` module (depending on which you are using), as well as the JavaFX modules (and include the path to it on the module path).

Comment: If you configure Eclipse to run JavaFX using Maven (which I recommend: see the appropriate instructions [here](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/)), then you should just be able to add the maven dependency for `org.jnetpcap` and it should "just work".